# How to display the div elements in row by row

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a html code which displays ads ,but the ads are display like a coloumn vise, but I want them to display in a horizontal row .How can we display the horizontal rows.And ads are which are coming dynamically based on the user selection.How can we display these ads in a row wise fashion .

Html code is :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" id="adsid"></div>
</div>
```

Code snippet from JS:

```
<input type="checkbox" id=' + s[i]['id']['0'] + ' />
<a href="#" class="list-group-item ">
    <input type="hidden" id="adsid" name="adsrunning" value=' + s[i]['id']["0"] + '/>
    <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">
        <font color="blue">' + s[i]['hea']["0"] + '</font>
    </h4>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">' + s[i]['desc']["0"] + '</p>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">' + s[i]['desc2']["0"] + '</p>
    <p class="list-group-item-text">
        <font color="green">' + s[i]['url']["0"] + '</font>
    </p>
</a><br/>
```

And JS is :

```
$("#groupid").change(function () {
    $("#adsid").html("");

    var grpvalue = $("#groupid").val();
    var accid = $('#accountid').val();
    var adsarray = [];
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: 'json',
        url: "pages/ads.php",
        data: "adgroup=" + grpvalue + "&accid=" + accid,
        success: function (s) {
            for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {

                var head = s[i]['hea']["0"];
                //alert(head);
                var adid = s[i]['id']["0"];
                var desc1 = s[i]['desc']["0"];
                var desc2 = s[i]['desc2']["0"];
                var url = s[i]['url']["0"];
                var p = document.createElement('p');
                var txt = document.createTextNode(head);
                p.appendChild(txt);
                //$('adsid').append(p);  
                adsarray.push(head, adid, desc1, desc2, url);

                $("#adsid").append("");
                $("#adsid").append('<input type="checkbox" id=' + s[i]['id']['0'] + ' /><a href="#" class="list-group-item "><input type="hidden" id="adsid" name="adsrunning" value=' + s[i]['id']["0"] + '/><h4 class="list-group-item-heading"><font color="blue">' + s[i]['hea']["0"] + '</font></h4><p class="list-group-item-text">' + s[i]['desc']["0"] + '</p><p class="list-group-item-text">' + s[i]['desc2']["0"] + '</p><p class="list-group-item-text"><font color="green">' + s[i]['url']["0"] + '</font></p></a><br/>');

            }
        }
    });
});
```

And Json Data is:

```
[{
    "hea": {
        "0": "Kidney Stone Removal"
    },
    "id": {
        "0": "40602813172"
    },
    "desc": {
        "0": "Get treated at top kidney center"
    },
    "desc2": {
        "0": "Take a free advice from our experts"
    },
    "url": {
        "0": "www.ainuindia.com"
    }
}]
```

Comment: what's your css for the concerning divs?

Comment: sorry,I haven't created any css class for this.but I am expecting the users may provide the solution in the css .that is why I have added a css tag to it.!

Comment: Use `float` or `display: inline-block`

Comment: The HTML snippet being appended through the JS will be looping and inserting 1 or more ads.  Each ad should be enclosed in a block level element, which should probably be floated or set to be an inline block.  The `font` tag should not be used, it is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the html of ad, try replacing `col-md-3` by `col-sm12` so the whole thing would read:

```
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12" id="adsid">

   </div>
 </div>
```

I'm assuming you're using bootstrap, so having `col-md-3` makes it float left with width 33%. On medium screen.

Answer (score 0):

I think your questions i answered here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

Use float to place the "rows" next to each other.
Though i would recommend you to change your "row" class to something more appropriate if possible. Since row are explicitly saying that it's a row, in other words a vertical alignment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ul li tag as bellow give style to li as list-style:none

```
<div class="row">
        <ul >
          <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src=""  /><span class="badge">Lorem ipsum</span></a></li>
          <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src=""  /><span class="badge">Lorem ipsum</span></a></li>
          <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src=""  /><span class="badge">Lorem ipsum</span></a></li>
          <li class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6"><a href="#"><img src=""  /><span class="badge">Lorem ipsum</span></a></li>

        </ul>
   </div>
```